# how to train dataset with 100 classes using yolov5

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, training-data, yolov5

I need to train a dataset with 100 classes. Each class has 200 images. Has anyone trained such a large dataset using yolo v5 previously? What GPU have you required?

Answer (score 1):

For a 200 images per class it could even work on a P100 (AWS TxDN) could take about 3 hrs to fulfil.